# Charging time of capacitor when used with this transistor configuration?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, circuit-analysis

I´m trying to calculate the charging time of the capacitor in this circuit.

[image: put circuit with capacitor]

I know the PUT is on when the voltage in the anode is higher than the Vp

```
 Va > Vp
 Va > Vg + 0.7
```

For this circuit Vcc = 15v

Having the voltage in the gate and Vp:

[image: Voltage in the gate]

```
 Vg = 10v
 Vp = 10.7v
```

With that the capacitor is going to charge to 10.7v, and then is going to discharge through the Rk resistor.

How to find the charging time of the capacitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the PUT being off and Q1 operating in linear mode, the capacitor is charged with a constant current. We know that: `Ic = C * dv/dt` . Ic is constant and has to be calculated. So the equation reduced to `(V2 - V1)/T = Ic/C` in which V2 is the voltage value of cap, V1 is the initial value and T is the time of charging and has to be calculated: 
`Vb(Q1) = 20/25 * 15 = 12` 
`V(R4k) = (15-12-0.7), V(R4k)/4 = 0.575mA = Ic` 
`(10.7 - 0)/T = 0.575 / 1uF` 
 find T ... 
T = 18.6 ms